# Flutter: compute the difference of the results of two queries from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to compute a list of "leagues" my user doesn't belong to. I was able to compute the list of leagues the user belongs to, but when I compute the difference between the two lists nothing is removed, since elements are 'Instance of '. How should I proceed?

I looked in the documentation but it's not possible to use "ArrayNotContains", and members is an array of document references to the collection "users".

```
import '/models/league_model.dart';
import '/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class DBFuture {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;


  Future<List<LeagueModel>> getLeaguesToJoin(DocumentReference? user) async {
    QuerySnapshot stream = await _firestore
        .collection("leghe")
        .where('members', arrayContains: user)
        .get();

    List<LeagueModel> result = [];

    for (var doc in stream.docs) {
      result.add(LeagueModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(doc: doc));
    }
    
    QuerySnapshot streamall = await _firestore.collection("leghe").get();

    List<LeagueModel> resultall = [];

    for (var doc in streamall.docs) {
      resultall.add(LeagueModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(doc: doc));
    }

    List<LeagueModel> difference = resultall.toSet().difference(result.toSet()).toList();

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you compare using an attribute of each object (like an ID) instead of comparing the entire object?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to get the difference lists of the IDs, but then I still need to return a list of instances of the class, not only the IDs